# CSS3: Base state, animation and back

Tags: css

Basically, I have an element with a given width and height. When I add the "zoomed" class to it, I want it to change its size and position. I got it working with a proper webkit-animation (keyframed).

The problem is that when I remove the "zoomed" class, it suddenly reverts to the original size and position, and I'd love to do it with an animation.

Note that this is an example that could probably be solved with the use of the transition property, but in my real world case, it can't because I have a fairly complex keyframed animation.

So, how to have a basic state, animate to a new state when a class is added and reverse the animation to the basic state when the class is removed? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try buiding the animation in a different class and thn toggling them... for example add `zoom-out` before removing `zoomed` having specified your animation for `zoom-out` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have wouldn't be solved with a transition.

What makes a transition work in both ways is that usually you set it in a class, and change properties in an state. This way, you have the transition set all the time, and only change the properties.

If you set the transition in the changed state only, once you remove it, the transition is no longer in the element, and so the change is immediate.

If adding the class is really the procedure that you want (for some other reason), the you have 3 posibilities

1. As suggested in the comment, in the change to the basic state you should add another class that has as only property the animation playing in reverse.
2. In the base element set the animation in reverse, in the added class set the animation.
3. Go to an elaborate system where you really remove the class in the animation end event, and what you do triggers that (way too complicated I think)

   There is no way that the element is *animated - transitioned - whatever* once you remove that from the element